# Changing a custom attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have created a custom server control for ASP which has a boolean 'Preview' attribute, based on this attribute, the image will either be displayed as a low, or high res image.

Until the entire page has loaded, I want Preview = true, once the page has loaded, this should turn to false to replace all images with their higher quality versions. The backend of the control is complete and I can control the quality manually by changing the attribute in the markup.

Here's what I have so far

```
<CustomControls:ImageControl ID="CustomImageTest" FileName="/lion.jpg" Alt="Lion" MaxWidth="800" MaxHeight="800" Preview="true" PreviewQuality="10" DestinationFolder="~/Images/WorkingFolder/" runat="server" />
```

I have then used this JavaScript to try and achieve the effect I'm after

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $("#CustomImageTest").attr("Preview", "false"); //Change attribute so high quality will be shown

//Testing to check that the function is being called
   var dNow = new Date();
   var localDate = dNow.getHours() + '/' + dNow.getMinutes() + '/' + dNow.getSeconds() + dNow.getMilliseconds();

$(".jsOutput").text("Everything has now loaded" + localDate).css("background-color", "");
});
```

I can tell that the function is being called as the jsOutput class that I am using updates when the page is fully loaded.

Do I need to refresh something to see the changes, am I referencing my element wrong?

Comment: I guess you have server-side code in your control that checks value of the attribute and loads image according to that value. Once page is loaded and displayed in client's browser you only change value of that parameter in the markup but it doesn't trigger page reload and image change.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that, `#CustomImageTest` is not available , that control id might be different, so you need to use `ClientID` like this. To verify, check view-source, if there is id with `CustomImageTest` exists in page.

`$("#<%=CustomImageTest.ClientID %>")`